# Unable to change mysql business engine

Tags: mysql

I am running following query:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; 
ALTER TABLE businesses ENGINE = MYISAM;
```

But still getting this message even after turning off foreign key checks.

```
#1217 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

This is under phpMySQLAdmin, it works on SQLYog though this same script.